# wondering if this recursive equation formula for the magnitude zeta function is correct.

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers, recursion

The formula is this

$$(z^*_m)^2= (z^*_{m-1})^2+\frac{1}{m^{2a}}-\frac{2z^*_{m-1}*cos(\pi-(j+b))}{m^{a}}$$

$$B= acos(\frac{(z^*_{m-2})^2-(z^*_{m-1})^2+\frac{1}{m^{2a}}}{z^*_{m-1}*m^{a}})$$

$$J=ln(\frac{m}{m-1})x$$ 
where Z*_m is the magnitue of the zeta function at a given sum m

Here is how I arrived at it
if we look at
$$\sum_{n=0}^m \frac{1}{n^s}$$

EDIT

S=a+ix

end EDIT

(note this all only works for values of M>3)

for values where it is defined, it can be potted on a complex plain.

[image]

it must then have a radial magnitude associated with it. Z*_m

if M is greater than 2 we can plot the values which add to it.

[image]

which means with law of cosines

$$(z^*_m)^2= (z^*_{m-1})^2+\frac{1}{m^{2a}}-\frac{2z^*_{m-1}*cos(k)}{m^{a}}$$

we can find K if we look at how we added to z*_{m-1}
[image]
$$(z^*_m)^2= (z^*_{m-1})^2+\frac{1}{m^{2a}}-\frac{2z^*_{m-1}*cos(\pi-(j+b))}{m^{a}}$$
we can find b with the law of cosines
$$B= acos(\frac{(z^*_{m-2})^2-(z^*_{m-1})^2+\frac{1}{m^{2a}}}{z^*_{m-1}*m^{a}})$$
and we can find J with as 
$$J=ln(\frac{m}{m-1})x$$

Update:
I wrote a python program to check whether it works or not.
you need to keep x and b small to avoid rounding erros.
making m to hi also can creat rounding errors.
you can find a link hear 
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8YKu_MJDZkGUW5qcVZZekctNXc

Update2: I was asked in the coments to explain why I thought this was interesting
the thought is i can say

given 
$$(z^*_m)^2= (z^*_{m-1})^2+\frac{1}{m^{2a}}-\frac{2z^*_{m-1}*cos(\pi-(j+b))}{m^{a}}$$
set z*_m to 0
and use the quadrac formual on Z*_(m-1)
$$z*_(m-1)=(\frac{2*cos(\pi-(j+b))}{m^{a}}+/-\sqrt{\frac{4*cos(\pi-(j+b))^2-4}{m^{2a}}})/2$$
z*_(m-1) is a scailer and cannot be imigary therefor cos(\pi-(j+b))=1 or -1
therefor
$$z*_{(m-1)}=+/-\frac{1}{m^{a}}$$
therefor if z*_m=0
$$z*_m=(0 or_\frac{4}{m^{2a}})/2$$
and its zero becuse of corse it is. i forgot the 1/2 in the quadric and they messed me up
but i can say

$$z*_{(m-1)}=\frac{1}{m^{a}}$$
and J+B=pi+3pi*n
Whitch you can see by the picture.
i feel kinda silly. 
I still think it kinda cool anyway!

Comment: I also made a video thought it's not very good      https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dPZjRRb4f9E&t=1s I have been working on a program to test it. (the formula that is)and will post it when I'm done.

Comment: Do you realize you are just asking how to add two complex numbers $r_1 e^{i \theta_1},r_2 e^{i \theta_2}$ and how to put $a+ib$ in the form $r e^{i \theta}$ ? And as you can see for addition it is better to represent complex numbers as $a+ib$..

Comment: Yea but if you do it this way you get to have the magnitude of the zeta function. which means there are no scalers and there are no imaginary numbers. I will edit the post to explain why I thought I thought this was interesting.

Comment: You didn't say anything more than for $\Re(s) > 1$, $|\zeta(s)| = \lim_{N \to \infty} |\sum_{n=1}^N n^{-s}|$. It is not interesting to replace complex numbers by something else, but if it helps you to understand, good for you.

Comment: oh, I forgot it was only true for R(s)>1 =p never mind about what I added then. i fixed that edit

Comment: I think I can make the same statement with the Dirichlet series, or a similar enof one to solve the series.

Comment: Because you tried to avoid complex numbers you obtained this mess. Your "update 2" doesn't mean anything.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65918/discussion-between-alex2060-and-reuns).